# How can I define a Dictionary with string key in AS3?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, dictionary, key

How can I define a Dictionary with string key in AS3? and how to do read operation?
for example:

```
var Dic:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
Dic["Exhausted"] = "He who talks more is sooner exhausted, please keep smiling :)";
String str = str.substring(8,str.length-1); // == str = "Exhausted";
trace('Dic[' + str + '] = ' + Dic[str]);
```

the output is Dic[Exhausted] = undefined???!!

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error on this line:

```
String str = str.substring(8,str.length-1);
```

If you just use this :

```
var d:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
d["Exhausted"] = "He who talks more is sooner exhausted, please keep smiling :)";

trace(d["Exhausted"]);
```

You can see it's all fine.

The problem with `var str:String = str.substring(8,str.length-1);` is that you define a String named "str": `var str:String`, but you assign a value which is the result of the `substring()` method called on str and of cours str does not exist yet when you call substring on it.
Not sure if this makes sense: you define str as the result of applying substring on str.

The actionscript compiler should've complained btw:

> expected a definition keyword (such as function) after attribute String, not str.

Just a wild guess, but would you happen to have str defined somewhere else in your code and you just update str again using str before using it ? In which case, you shouldn't redefine, str, you should simply assign a new value.
e.g.

```
//somewhere else
var str:String = "12345678Exhausted";
//further down
var Dic:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
Dic["Exhausted"] = "He who talks more is sooner exhausted, please keep smiling :)";
str = str.substring(8,str.length); // == str = "Exhausted";
trace('Dic[' + str + '] = ' + Dic[str]);
```

Also, another syntax error is how you define `str`:
should be `var str:String` (as2/as3 syntax), not `String str`(java/c++/etc. style)

Comment: First of all, I am Java person, so excuse me from the typo of String syntax,,,,Yes, I got "str" form above line (sorry for not including this information)
In details:{var str:String = emotions[i].toString();
str = str.substring(8,str.length-1); // I use this line to get the name of the object which I used its name as a key of the Dic.
trace('Dic[' + str + '] = ' + Dic[str]);}

Comment: Yes, In short, I need to pop a value from the dictionary while the key is a variable! ex: `Dic[x] while x is a variable` , assume that I got x-value from another code. how come?

Comment: by "pop a value" do you mean removing it from the dictionary, of accessing/using the value ? If you want to delete a key/value pair from a `Dictionary` object use the `delete` keyword: `delete Dic[x];`. If you want to check if a key exists and use it, check for `undefined` like so: `if(Dic[x] != undefined) trace("found x:",Dic[x]);`. HTH

Comment: for sure it helps especially to know how the dictionary works in AS3..I meant by pop yea to search or get a value by its key...however, I tried your code and it works!! till now I donna know why when I return the string key from the substring function and use it to retrieve its value,,it returns "undefined" !! I will give it another look, Thanks a lot dear George for your useful reply ...(Y)

Comment: @ مريم قد الحياة Notice in my code I do something like `var str:String = "12345678Exhausted";
str = str.substring(8,str.length);
` and not `str.substring(8,str.length-1);` which would return "Exhauste", which of course would be an invalid/undefined key. Would this be your problem ? Also, you can use `str.substring(8);` because if you don't pass the second argument, the end of the string is assumed as the second index. HTH

Comment: in my code I get the class name which is they key of the Dictionary, so the first value of str before substring it is `[object Exhausted]` according to this line: `var str:String = emotions[i].toString();` then I want to get the class name with is "Exhausted" I use return value of this line: `str = str.substring(8,str.length-1);` is "Exhausted" so the value of str now is the right key...when I call Dic[str], it returns "undifined"!!

Comment: `Geoooorge...it works... :) it is my fault...I didn't call the function that initiates the dictionary with the corresponding key-value pairs!! I am so sorry for this fake question! But really I gain a lot form this conversation...nice to meet you and thanks a lot for your cooperation and help...`